# Unauthorized users return status 500 instead of 401 when using phpunit test

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-passport

I'm working with buddy.works for continuous integration of my project. The issue is though, my phpunit tests pass on my local computer but fail on the buddy works pipeline.

I have tried googling and reading for over two days now and although I found many similar problems, I haven't encountered a solution that can even point me in the right direction.

```php
    public function test_orders_route_unauthenticated_user () {

        $data = [
            'orderID'      => '001241',
            'sku'          => '123456',
            'quantity'     => 9,
            'pricePerUnit' => 78,
            'priceTotal'   => 702,
        ];

        $this->json('POST', 'api/orders', [$data])->assertStatus(401);

    }
```

The test fails with status code 500 instead of 401 and I don't know what is causing this.

Edit:
Laravel 5.8.17, php unit which comes integrated with it, works as expected until being run on buddy works.

Comment: What do your logs say? A 500 should leave an entry

Comment: 500 means server error, so you are not even reaching the endpoint. Try looking at your logs. use `$this->withoutExceptionHandling()` for full stacktrace.

Comment: Unfortunetly I can't access the logs as on my machine it works fine, it's only when buddy works runs the test it fails.

Comment: Tests\Feature\ProductsControllerTest::test_products_route_unauthenticated_user
Expected status code 401 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.
/buddy/management-products-api-3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:133
/buddy/management-products-api-3/tests/Feature/ProductsControllerTest.php:45
FAILURES!

Comment: Do you use Postman or something to test your API. Because clearly your `api/orders` is not reachable, hence the 500. You've got to check if the app is running at all on the server.

Comment: With postman without auth, it redirects to Login page... this is most likely the issue?

Comment: No, because that's a 302 status code, redirect. 500 means that something is wrong on your server, it fails to reach the endpoint.

Comment: Hmm well postman gives me status 200 and shows the login page :S

Comment: And you try to send the same data using the same endpoint? and application/type = json? We are talking about the server, not on the local endpoint

Comment: Yeah same endpoint, but the endpoint is localhost. Application/json is also set.

Comment: The problem seems fine locally, everything works as expected, but as soon as the test is run on buddy.works it fails

Comment: You have the problem on the server my friend, not locally, so stop testing locally. Because the problem is on your server, you need to solve it there. It seems like your app on buddy works does not work at all.

Comment: @CMHayden Did you ever manage to solve this issue? I'm facing the same situation

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem while testing my laravel 8 api.
I had to send header with my request.

```
public function testGetUsersWithoutAuthentication()
{
    $response = $this->withHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json',])->get('api/users');
    $response->assertStatus(401);
}
```

Comment: it's a routing problem because it's trying to redirect you to the login page...but it's an api...and I suspect you don't have a login webpage which is fine